# Get list of all content type associated with a list

Tags: list, javascript, content-type, 2016, sharepoint-rest-api

I am using client code using JQuery and rest API where I have a requirement to 
 bind a  drop down control with the content type names associated with a particular list.

I am working on SharePoint 2016 on-premise.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using below endpoint:

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Display name of List')/contenttypes
```

**OR**

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/lists(listid)/contenttypes
```

**official documentation**: [SP.ContentTypeCollection object - REST resource endpoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj247038(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#rest-resource-endpoint).

**Update**:

Try using something like below to fetch the names of content type. This is like pseudo code for your reference. You can check the exact data you are getting from REST call by adding break-point inside `success` function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('Display name of List')/contenttypes?$select=Name,Id",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var optionsArray = [];
        if(data.d && data.d.results) {
            for(var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
                console.log(data.d.results[i].Name);
                // Push the content type name in array
                optionsArray.push(data.d.results[i].Name);
            }
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/lists(listid)/contenttypes , this gives me a list of content type. 
Can you please suggest me how to get all those values in an array please so that I can bind them in the dropdown control

Comment: try to run the loop on `data.d.results` in success function of `GET` call

Comment: Try using the code given in update section in my answer and let me know if it works for you or if you face any issues.

Comment: Thank you so much Ganesh. 
It worked perfectly !
Much Appreciated, Thank once again :)

Answer (score 0):

With GET request you can get all the content types of your specified list

.../_api/web/lists(ID)/contenttypes

I recommend to use extension in your Browser Called SharePoint Insider, it will help you a lot to figure out the endpoints that will help you to build your REST request

Best regards.